# card.io UI issues on 4" ios devices

Tags: ios, card.io

card.io is working fine on ios 3.5" devices but on 4" devices the camera view remains the same and the rest space is fully occupied by the bottom toolbar. Is there any way to control the view size of camera and toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josh from card.io here. The issue has been fixed, as of Dec 4, 2012. Please go grab the latest SDK from card.io/integrate

Comment: Thanks Josh for your quick response. Could you please tell me when can we expect this issue fixed?

Comment: I don't have a good estimate for you at this point, sorry. Shouldn't be too long, though.